# Can the inside of a block be aware of the selector it received and evaluate itself based on that?

Tags: arguments, block, smalltalk, function-composition

Presume we have a block in the code somewhere and we assign it to a variable (either instance or local) like this.

```
someName := [ anInstanceVariable doThis. anotherInstanceVariable doThat.]
```

From the outside I would like to use it this way:

```
someName someMessageTheBlockDoesntImplement: argument.
```

Would it be possible for the block to act on the specific selector `someName` and have `anInstanceVariable` or `anotherInstanceVariable` perform it and return those objects respectively?

PS. It would act as a kind of forwarder of sorts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is fairly confusing. First i guess you meant "the selector someMessageTheBlockDoesntImplement:" and not "someName". But what you are basically asking for is being able to make forwarding proxies.

You normally do not use BlockClosures to do that, instead you create a class MyForwarder which inherits either Object or even ProtoObject (depending on which Smalltalk you use and how transparent you want the forwarder to be).

Add your two instance variables in this class so that you can hold them and some method so you can set them etc.

Then you implement `#doesNotUnderstand:` in MyForward which looks something like:

```
doesNotUnderstand: aMessage
    aMessage selector == #thisMessageGoesToFirstGuy
        ifTrue: [
             ^ firstGuy perform: aMessage selector withArguments: aMessage arguments ] 
        ifFalse: [
             ^ secondGuy perform: aMessage selector withArguments: aMessage arguments ]
```

Code not tested but you get the idea.

Comment: Yes, forwarding proxies is exactly what I'm trying to create, however I'd like them as transparent as possible for them to be able to forward all messages. I am looking for a way to achive this without going as deep as to modify the Compiler to add this kind of support.

Comment: If you subclass ProtoObject you can make quite transparent proxies. In fact, they can be so transparent that they get quite hard to debug :). I do know that Magma (the Squeak OODB) has such proxies, so you might want to take a look there. Chris Muller knows more of course.

Answer (score 6):

All Smalltalk dialects allow some way to access the current context. In VisualWorks and Pharo, you use #thisContext. So if you have a method like...

```
Object>>someMethod
    ^[thisContext sender inspect] value
```

...send evaluate: 'abc' someMethod ... you'll get aMethodContext --> ByteString(Object)>>someMethod

or...

```
Object>>someMethod: aBlock
    ^aBlock value
```

'abc' someMethod: [thisContext sender inspect]

--> ByteString(Object)>>someMethod:

If you need to see more of the stack, you can use something like...

```
| context frames | 
context := thisContext.
frames := OrderedCollection new.
[context isNil or: [context stack isNil]] whileFalse: [
    frames add: context.
    context := context sender].
^frames
```

In VA Smalltalk, you could write...

```
someMethod
    ^[Processor activeProcess currentFrame context inspect] value
```

...a BlockContextTemplate --> [] in Object>>#someMethod

Looking at debugger code is a good way to see what other techniques you could use.

Answer (score 3):

You can always implement `doesNotUnderstand:` of the `BlockClosure` class in a way:

```
doesNotUnderstand: aMessage
    ^ self value: aMessage selector value: aMessage arguments
```

and then you have to have a block like this:

```
[ :selector :args |
    ^ { anInstanceVariable      perform: selector withArguments: args.
        anotherInstanceVariable perform: selector withArguments: args } ]
```

But why do you want to do something like that?

Comment: Interesting! One could compare that :selector to anything in the context where block is declared in, and choose if anInstance or anotherInstance performs it. I'm trying to add some features to Smalltalk without modifying the compiler, this has led me to explore message passing and delegation as an alternative.